# Полоса прокрутки

Tags: android, eclipse

На экране кнопки, поля для ввода, разложенные по LinearLayout, 2 gridview, содержимое которых не помещается в экран. Все это находится в ScrollView. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы полоса прокрутки появлялась не в каждом gridview, а на экране в целом.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Multiplication" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Stroki" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Stolb" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Заполнить матрицу" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Отобразить" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/llMain"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Введите число" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Умножить" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, не правильно класть Scroll в Scroll... 
Но есть ситуации, когда без этого никак... 
Я сделал у себя так:
Рассчитываю сумму высоты всех элементов внутреннего скролла, и выставляю ему высоту.
Я это конкретно делал с ListView, вложенным в ScrollView

Comment: спасибо за идею. высота всех элементов есть, не подскажите,как выставить высоту внутреннего скролла. не могу найти((

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть оба GridView в ScrollView

**UPD**
Попробуйте поменять местами ваш первый LinearLayout и ScrollView. Мне думается так будет правильнее.

Comment: ... или обоих в LinearLayout, а LinearLayout в ScrollView

Comment: Там все в ScrollView а полоса прокрутки появляется только в gridview

Comment: покажи код

Comment: поменяла ,полоса прокрутки появляется на каждом GridView, Видно две строки, остальные приходится прокручивать даже когда содержимое, по идее, умещается т.е. место еще остается внизу.

Comment: по идеи у грида и должны быть свои полосы прокрутки. А его элементы точно не листаются?

Comment: мне нужно, что бы эти полосы были не у грида, а прокручивался весь экран целиком

Comment: запретите у грида полосы прокрутки(scrollbars=none). В остальном как я понимаю экран и так листается, но верните как у вас было изначально. На самом деле гриды внутрь скроллвью ложить не рекомендуется, но попробовать стоило во всяком случае.